# Perforce - Delete files from a Stream

Tags: perforce

I created a new Stream in Perforce and populated it from my local folder.
Inadvertently - I added all object files as well.

Now I want to delete all object files - *.o from the depot for a stream 
i.e. something like P4 delete //myDepot/myStream/*.o (recursively)

Looked at the the P4 commands but can't seem to locate a command that will do that

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
p4 delete //myDepot/myStream/....o
```

Comment: Client 'Pedro-Win7b' unknown - use client command to create it
 ?? Why do I need a client - I am deleting from the depot?

Comment: Are you the owner of this Perforce repo? If so, you can use 'p4 obliterate', which doesn't need a client. But IT LEAVES NO HISTORY, either, so it should only be used for cleaning up boo-boos, like the one you describe.